# Memory Issue When Executing Quantum Circuit on AWS Braket with qiskit

Tags: qiskit, grovers-algorithm, oracles, amazon-braket, memory-space

**Description:**
I'm currently facing memory-related issues while trying to execute quantum circuits as a hybrid job on the aws tensor network simulator 'tn1' using Qiskit. Despite various attempts to mitigate the issue, such as using multiple instance types and increasing storage, I still encounter memory-related errors.

**Attempted Solutions:**

1.Tried using multiple instance types on AWS Braket to see if higher memory capacity would solve the issue.

2.Added additional storage to the instance in case it was a disk space issue.
Reduced the size of the quantum circuit to minimize memory usage, but the problem persists.

**Circuit Specifications:**
The quantum circuit I'm trying to execute consists of a Grover oracle and a diffusion circuit. The Grover oracle includes various quantum gates such as Hadamard (H), Controlled-NOT (CNOT), and rotational gates (e.g., Rz). The diffusion circuit is composed of Hadamard gates, multi-controlled X gates, and single-qubit X gates.
The circuit is designed to perform a specific quantum computation task, and it's crucial for my project to execute it successfully.

**Memory Usage:**
Despite my efforts to optimize the circuit and the instance configuration, I'm still hitting memory limits during execution.
I've checked the memory usage during execution, and it seems to exceed the available memory on the instance, leading to errors.

The **Size of the Deployment package** is **5.15kb** and it is a '**.tar.gz**' that i upload to a s3 bucket and Run as a Hybrid Job

**The Grover oracle:**

```
def create_grover_oracle(target, num_qubits):
    qr = QuantumRegister(num_qubits)
    oracle_circuit = QuantumCircuit(qr)

    # to encode the target into the quantum state
    for i, bit in enumerate(address):
        if bit == '1':
            oracle_circuit.x(i)

    # apply CZ gates pairwise between adjacent qubits
    for i in range(num_qubits - 1):
        oracle_circuit.cz(i, i+1)

    # uncompute the encoding
    for i, bit in enumerate(target):
        if bit == '1':
            oracle_circuit.x(i)

    return oracle_circuit
```

**The Diffusion circuit:**

```
def create_diffusion_circuit(num_qubits):
    qr = QuantumRegister(num_qubits)
    diffusion_circuit = QuantumCircuit(qr)

    # apply Hadamard gates to all qubits
    diffusion_circuit.h(range(num_qubits))

    # apply X gate to all qubits
    diffusion_circuit.x(range(num_qubits))

    # apply multi-controlled Z gate
    diffusion_circuit.h(num_qubits-1)
    diffusion_circuit.mct(list(range(num_qubits-1)), num_qubits-1)
    diffusion_circuit.h(num_qubits-1)

    # apply X gate again
    diffusion_circuit.x(range(num_qubits))

    # apply Hadamard gates again
    diffusion_circuit.h(range(num_qubits))

    return diffusion_circuit
```

**The execute_quantum_circuit function:**

```
def execute_quantum_circuit(circuit, shots=1000):
    backend = AWSBraketProvider().get_backend("TN1")
    transpiled_circuit = transpile(circuit, backend)
    memory_estimate = get_memory_estimate(transpiled_circuit)
    print(f"Memory needed for the transpiled circuit: {memory_estimate} bytes")
    job = backend.run(transpiled_circuit, shots=shots)

    # Get the result of the job
    result = job.result()
    # Get the counts of measurement outcomes
    counts = result.get_counts()

    return counts
```

**The Error:**

```
ClientError: Please use an instance type with more memory, or reduce the size of job data processed on an instance.
```

**The Print Statement in execute def:**

```
Memory needed for the transpiled circuit: 930 bytes
```

**The Traceback Log:**

```
INFO:qiskit.passmanager.base_tasks:Pass: ContainsInstruction - 0.01764 (ms)

INFO:qiskit.passmanager.base_tasks:Pass: UnitarySynthesis - 0.01287 (ms)

INFO:qiskit.passmanager.base_tasks:Pass: HighLevelSynthesis - 0.74935 (ms)

INFO:qiskit.transpiler.passes.basis.basis_translator:Begin BasisTranslator from source basis {('x', 1), ('cz', 2)} to target basis {'z', 'cy', 'ecr', 'ry', 'ryy', 'barrier', 'cp', 'iswap', 'sdg', 'swap', 'h', 'sxdg', 'y', 'measure', 'id', 'sx', 's', 'cz', 'tdg', 'rzz', 'rx', 'x', 'rxx', 'rz', 'cx', 'snapshot', 'p', 't'}.

INFO:qiskit.transpiler.passes.basis.basis_translator:Basis translation path search completed in 0.000s.

INFO:qiskit.transpiler.passes.basis.basis_translator:Basis translation paths composed in 0.000s.

INFO:qiskit.transpiler.passes.basis.basis_translator:Basis translation instructions replaced in 0.000s.

INFO:qiskit.passmanager.base_tasks:Pass: BasisTranslator - 1.15204 (ms)

INFO:qiskit.passmanager.base_tasks:Pass: Depth - 0.14234 (ms)

INFO:qiskit.passmanager.base_tasks:Pass: FixedPoint - 0.00954 (ms)

INFO:qiskit.passmanager.base_tasks:Pass: Size - 0.08893 (ms)

INFO:qiskit.passmanager.base_tasks:Pass: FixedPoint - 0.00644 (ms)

INFO:qiskit.passmanager.base_tasks:Pass: Optimize1qGatesDecomposition - 0.33641 (ms)

INFO:qiskit.passmanager.base_tasks:Pass: CXCancellation - 0.16832 (ms)

INFO:qiskit.passmanager.base_tasks:Pass: GatesInBasis - 0.30541 (ms)

INFO:qiskit.passmanager.base_tasks:Pass: Depth - 0.12088 (ms)

INFO:qiskit.passmanager.base_tasks:Pass: FixedPoint - 0.00834 (ms)

INFO:qiskit.passmanager.base_tasks:Pass: Size - 0.06461 (ms)

INFO:qiskit.passmanager.base_tasks:Pass: FixedPoint - 0.00691 (ms)

INFO:qiskit.passmanager.base_tasks:Pass: ContainsInstruction - 0.00930 (ms)

INFO:qiskit.compiler.transpiler:Total Transpile Time - 28.49793 (ms)

Memory needed for the transpiled circuit: 930 bytes

INFO:qiskit.passmanager.base_tasks:Pass: ContainsInstruction - 0.00978 (ms)

INFO:qiskit.passmanager.base_tasks:Pass: UnitarySynthesis - 0.00715 (ms)

Code Run Finished

2024-02-28 01:00:27,628 sagemaker-training-toolkit ERROR Reporting training FAILURE

2024-02-28 01:00:27,628 sagemaker-training-toolkit ERROR ExecuteUserScriptError:

ExitCode 247

ErrorMessage ""

Command "/usr/local/bin/python3.10 braket_container.py"

2024-02-28 01:00:27,628 sagemaker-training-toolkit ERROR Encountered exit_code 1
```

**Need assistance:**

I would appreciate any insights or guidance on how to fix this memory issue and execute the quantum circuit on AWS Braket using Qiskit as Hybrid Job

**P.S.:** I have also attempted using diffrent instance type like mlg4dn16xlarge etc and increasing the additional instance storage to more like more than 80gb but encountered similar issues. i suspect it might be something related to how the project is deployed,extracted or something like sagemaker training causing it, maybe the needed storage spikes and cause the error
but as the deployment package and circuit requirement are quite small what could be causing the error.

Comment: Hey @Neel. I wasn't able to reproduce the memory issue yet. Would you mind to tell me a) how did you define `get_memory_estimate` and b) which circuit did you run? As mentioned in another post,I was able to run `execute_quantum_circuit(create_diffusion_circuit(2))` with hybrid job with no issue. Were you able to run this?

Comment: a)the get_memory_estimate def:
`def get_memory_estimate(transpiled_circuit):
 # converting the transpiled circuit to QASM
 qasm_str = transpiled_circuit.qasm()
 # calculate the length of the QASM string in bytes
  qasm_length = len(qasm_str.encode('utf-8'))
  return qasm_length`
b) after trying to debug the error i think it might be because im executing the circuits also as grover iterations and as it executes more iteration i think at one point it runs out of memory so i think i need to reduce the number of iterations to fix that

Comment: the grover iterations def:
`def grover_iterations(backend, correct_address, num_iterations):
 for iteration in range(num_iterations):
 print(f"Iteration: {iteration + 1}")
 results = execute_quantum_circuit(oracle_partition)`
but that also just a guess could be a problem with sagemaker training toolkit

Comment: @fagd how can i create a different docker image to not use the sagemaker training toolkit
as the last thing logs show for awhile is
`INFO:qiskit.passmanager.base_tasks:Pass: ContainsInstruction - 0.02432 (ms) INFO:qiskit.passmanager.base_tasks:Pass: UnitarySynthesis - 0.00954 (ms)`
and then
`sagemaker-training-toolkit ERROR`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I was able to use `get_memory_estimate` now. Fro your description, it appears that the circuit will get more complicated as you iterate. To better debug the memory issue, I would suggest starting from a simpler circuit, and gradually increase it's size manually. This may give you a sense of when to stop the iteration to avoid the memory issue.

Comment: Regarding how to create a different docker image, please refer to [this example](https://github.com/qiskit-community/qiskit-braket-provider/blob/main/docs/how_tos/3_how_to_qiskit_hybrid_job.ipynb) which shows how to create a customized docker image in Elastic Container Repository (ECR), followed by using the image to run qiskit circuits in hybrid job. Another related example maybe found [here](https://github.com/amazon-braket/amazon-braket-examples/blob/main/examples/hybrid_jobs/3_Bring_your_own_container/bring_your_own_container.ipynb).